# What is the Halloween Headstone?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was tiding yo my base when I came across this

[image]

I know that during Christmas there was a special object that could spawn which was a Christmas tree but it also had an extra benefit, I think it was a spell.

I am wondering, is there anything special about this Halloween Headstone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

THe `Halloween Headstone` is the same as the `Christmas tree` it only gives a different reward.

I just removed an `Halloween Headstone` and I got `75000 Elixer`.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5Y4cdAwkds) is a video about it.

I found multiple video's and on all of the video's people got `75000 Elixer`

So ask yourself is that 50k Elixer worth it Or do you want a nice Headstone?

Comment: Do you get another one if you remove it? And what is the pop rate? About the same as trees/bushes?

Comment: @JK01 I was wrong, it is possible to get multiple Headstone's. I just got another.It did took a weak for it to respawn.

Comment: Yeah I have 3 already :)

Comment: What was the reward for the christmas tree? I forgot:P

Comment: @Neffer_23 50k gold

Answer (score 2):

The first time when I removed Halloween Headstone, I got 75,000 Gold, and the second time was 75,000 Elixir!

Comment: umm they only reward in elixir